# laravel save multiple records with different checkbox values

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox

I have a form with some checkboxes and I want to save all the values of the checkboxes in multiple records, like save one value per record

```
       for($i=0; $i > $checkboc_count; $i++) {
          $destinatario = new Destinatario();
          $destinatario->acao_id = $acao1->id;
          if ($request->outros != null) {
            $destinatario->outros = $request->outros;
          }
          $destinatario->grupo_id = $request->get('grupos.' + $i);
          $destinatario->save();
}
```

Now I have this but it's not working.The record is not saved and there is no error returned.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Update:

Code of the view:

```
@foreach($grupo as $grupos)
                <label for="grupoid" class="control-label">{{$grupos->nome}}</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="grupos[]", value="{{$grupos->id}}", id="{{$grupos->nome}}">
                @endforeach
                <label for="grupoid" class="control-label">Outros</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="grupos", value="outros", id="outros" onclick="show_hide('#show')">
```

btw, now, i cant get the values of checkboxes, probably i will try to get them in a wrong way –

Comment: What exactly is not working? Do you get the checked checkbox values with `$request` ? Remember, that only the checked chekcboxes are submitted!

Comment: ya i know, what happens now is that when i subbmit, the records of the checked checkboxes isnt´t saved, and for exemple, the user checked 3 checkboxes with different value and i want to create 3 records with user and the checkboxes checked, one per one like user1----value1, user1---value2, user1---value3

Comment: As I mentioned, do you receive the `request` values? How and where is `$checkboc_count` set?

Comment: $checkbox_array = $_POST['grupos'];
      $checkboc_count = count($checkbox_array);

Comment: btw i update my first comment

Comment: please add your html code

Comment: Please add full form and full post method. And why are you mentioning Laravel but using `$_POST` ? Use laravel request objects for this!

Comment: Your 2nd input has just `grupos` so its overwriting others with a single input! Try changing that to `grupos[]` too.

Comment: @DainisAbols, i use $_POST because  it wasn´t working with $request->...

Comment: Can it possibly have to do with the fact that not-checked checkboxed will not be a part of the request by default?

Comment: @DainisAbols now, i try to change grupos[] but nothing more happens

Comment: @ThomasMoors but i just want to save the checked checkboxes

Comment: btw, now, i cant get the values of checkboxes, probably i will try to get them in a wrong way

Comment: i just solve it, but the code just save me the first record, when i check 3 ckeckboxes

Answer (score 1):

you need to replace `>` to `<`

```
for($i=0; $i < $checkboc_count; $i++)
```

Comment: Nice, didn't spot this one

Comment: we are also beginners :)

Comment: btw, now, i cant get the values of checkboxes, probably i will try to get them in a wrong way

Comment: i just solve it, but the code just save me the first record, when i check 3 ckeckboxes